# Create a row in an existing data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to insert new email dresses via survey using ampscript in an existing data extension (TEST_LANDING) where all my contacts are already. 
I tried with `InsertDE` and `updateData` function and it works but only insert email.

Here is my code :

```
set @newemail= updatedata("TEST_landing",1,"EMAIL", @email) ==> it inserts well an email adress
```

So I tried with some other data to add :

```
set @newemail= updatedata("TEST_landing",1,"EMAIL", @email,"COUNTRY_CODE",FR, "LANGUAGE_CODE",fr, "CREATION_DATE",SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW(),"CHANNEL_LEVEL_1",Acquisition)
```

And it doesn't work.

Moreover does anyone know what is the difference between insertdata, insertDE, updatedata, updateDE, upsertData functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the 'DE' functions are to be used at send time inside of emails only
All the 'Data' functions are to be used in landing pages, script activities, etc.

Insert - Add New record only. If record already exists, it will throw an error.
Update - Update an existing record only. If record does not already exist, it will throw an error.
Upsert - Add and update. This will add a record if it does not exist, or update an existing record.

You also don't need to set it to a variable, you can just use the function by itself, like below:

```
%%[ 
    updatedata("TEST_landing",1,"EMAIL", @email,"COUNTRY_CODE","FR", "LANGUAGE_CODE","fr", "CREATION_DATE",SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW()),"CHANNEL_LEVEL_1", "Acquisition")
]%%
```

Please note that I added in quotes:

- to the FR for COUNTRY_CODE
- the fr for "LANGUAGE_CODE"
- Acquisition for "CHANNEL_LEVEL_1"

I also added an end parenthesis for your "CREATION_DATE" function.

This should now function as required. I usually recommend using the UPSERT option, unless you need to restrict it to add only or update only - in which case I would highly recommend having conditional statements around it to prevent this throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are missing the "" and you haven't closed the brackets on the function SystemDateToLocalDate().
Could you try this please :

```
@newemail= updatedata("TEST_landing",1,"EMAIL", @email,"COUNTRY_CODE","FR", "LANGUAGE_CODE","fr", "CREATION_DATE",SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW()),"CHANNEL_LEVEL_1","Acquisition")
```

-> Please check the link below to see difference between the ampscript functions
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm